# ALEXA ROS VOICE COMMAND TURTLEBOT

Tags: alexa-skills-kit, ros, voice

I have been able to integrated alexa to ROS, and in general terms it works, the problem is that when I send a command to alexa and it publishes a topic, turtlebot keeps listening to it, and for example, when I say forward, that is not a big deal because I can simply tell turtlebot to stop, but I find it kind of a problem when I say turn left or turn right, because it keeps going left or right, I am not sure how to solve this.

Type of messages I am publishing= geometry messages/ twist

My ideas:

1- Create a subscriber that subscribes just for a certain time then close and subscribes when a new command is publish.

Disadvantage: To go forward would required a longer time than going for the sides, so maybe would not solve the problem

2- Create a subscriber that subscribes gets only one message closes and subscribes when a new message is publish.

Disadvantage: to go forward just one time, would not solve this problems but would just create the exact opposite problem

I saw that for the second case I can use this but I am not sure how to.

```
  ros::topic::waitForMessage(..)
```

The code I have for the subscriber at the moment is this.

```
#include <ros/ros.h>
#include <geometry_msgs/Twist.h>

void cmd_vel_callback(const geometry_msgs::Twist& vel_cmd)
{ 
ROS_INFO("I heard: [%f]", vel_cmd.linear.y);
std::cout << "Twist Received " << std::endl;
}


int main( int argc, char* argv[] )
{
ros::init(argc, argv, "turtl" );

ros::NodeHandle n;
ros::Subscriber sub = n.subscribe("/cmd_vel", 1000, cmd_vel_callback);

while( n.ok() ) 
{
ros::spin();
}

return 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is you cannot just stop subscribing and subscribe again which is not optimal.

there's 2 way you can do this :

1. you can remove `ros::spin()` and use `ros::spinOnce()` ask subscriber to get new data after your previous task is done (You said for forward moving it takes longer and for sides takes shorter) you can call it after you can verify the task is done anywhere in the code.
2. get output from subscriber and store it inside another variable and add another control function inside your `while(n.ok())` to act on the previous data or to change to new data came from subscriber.